Symfony tests data provider with fixtures information
PHPUnit: 11.4
Symfony: 7.2
We have simple test with external data provider:
class AppTest {
    #[DataProviderExternal(AppDataProvider::class, 'getData')]
    public function testData(array $data): void {
        static::assertSame($data['type'], '123');
    }
}

class AppDataProvider {
    public static function getData(): array {
        return [
            [
                'data' => [
                    'type' => /* What code should be here?
                               * Something like static::fixtureManager()->getReference(AppTypeEnum::MAIN_TYPE->value)
                               */
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }
}

From source code I see that data provider set data for test via setData, but in this place test class is just created and no "setUp" was called or anything.
How can I get type to be taken from database fixtures in external data provider?
